# nginx showing default welcome page instead of directory on my webserver

Tags: nginx

I have Nginx set up on a remote Arch Linux server. I have files in `/srv/http/mywebsite.com`. ("mywebsite.com" is of course just the placeholder name I'm using for this question.)

In that directory are a bunch of files and pages. There is no `index.html`. Until recently, I could see all the files in the directory by going to `mywebsite.com`. But now, after running `yay -Syyu` to upgrade and update packages, and deleting files in `/var/spool/clientmqueue`, when I go to `mywebsite.com`, I only see the default "welcome" page by Nginx.

Here are the contents of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.
`
#user http;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

```
#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}
```

}`

In both `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` I have `mywebsite.com`, whose contents are as follows...

`server {
listen 443;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/mywebsite.com.key;

```
    server_name  mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
    location / {
            root /srv/http/mywebsite.com;
            index index.html;
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                    #
                    # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                    #
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                    #
                    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                    #
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                    return 204;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
            }
            if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
            }
    }
```

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with arch linux, but it doesn't look like your nginx.conf includes the sites-enabled conf directory, eg.:

```
http { 
    include mime.types; 
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*;

    <... rest of file ...>
}
```